# Is there a mistake in this example in my mechanics textbook?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, kinematics, work, textbook-erratum

This is a worked example in my mechanics book:

[image]

[image]

But I think this worked example is wrong. In the 6th line. shouldn't $X=4R$ as the expression for distance above the surface is $(X-R)$ and when the particle P is a distance of 3R ABOVE the surface, $v=0.5(gR)^{0.5}$

could someone please tell me if I am wrong or the book is wrong... I mean books a re rarely wrong and so I am not sure what to follow

Comment: looks wrong, yeah

Comment: @Cheeku: so the book is wrong?

Comment: Which book is the question from? There might be a list of errata online. It looks wrong to me.

Comment: _I mean books are rarely wrong_ They are wrong more than you could expect.

Comment: @innisfree: Edexcel AS and A Level Modular Mathematics - Mechanics 3

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong, it should be $7/4$, not $19/12$ inside the square root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the money, and DumpsterDoofus's got the right answer in the comments.

You can solve this problem quickly straight out using the Potential Energy for a Gravity Field formula (which is the one your book obtains on line 5):

$$U = -G\frac{Mm}{r}$$

- $r$ is distance from center of Earth
- note that this potential energy is *negative* -- this doesn't matter at all, just use it as usual

Since $g = \frac{GM}{R^2}$, we can use $U = -g\frac{R^2}{r}$ (compare with line 5, keeping in mind that your book is using $x$ instead of $r$).

So, simple conservation of energy gives us:

$$\frac{1}{2}v_0^2 - g\frac{R^2}{R} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{gR}{4} - g\frac{R^2}{4R}$$

Work it out and you'll find $v_0 = \sqrt{\frac{7}{4}gR}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong!

A clean way to see this is the equation where you have $\frac {gR^2}{x}$. Which clearly states the fact that $x$ has origin in the center of the earth. The author assumed that axis origin is on the surface of the earth, if that is true, then we should get $v=0$, when $x=0$. But the equation is undefined on $x=0$.